# nodejs crypto.pbkdf2 in Java

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, compatibility, pbkdf2

I'm migrating an app from NodeJs to Java and I'm struggling to re-create password encryption.

I've used NodeJs [`crypto.pbkdf2`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback) as follows:

```
crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, hashIterations, hashLength, function(err, derivedKey) {
  // ...
})
```

How can I achieve the same algorithm in Java? 
I've played a bit with [PBEKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/PBEKeySpec.html), with no success so far (I mostly didn't know what I was doing).

In case someone more knowledgeable than me finds this useful, here is the crypto source code:

- [JavaScript](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/lib/crypto.js#L596)
- [C++](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/370573665a4daba22655e00c8d0ae8577899d8e5/src/node_crypto.cc#L4519)

Thanks!

Comment: PBESpec is definitely a way to go if you want to use PBKDF2. Scroll down to the section"Advanced password security using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 algorithm" on this page for an example.  http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/22/how-to-generate-secure-password-hash-md5-sha-pbkdf2-bcrypt-examples/

Comment: Sure, but the problem is that I need to implement it *exactly* the same way as in NodeJs.

Comment: As long as your inputs are the same, it should work.